# I need extract all characters or numbers prior to a word using regex

Tags: regex

I need extract all characters or numbers prior to a word using regex

**Case 1**

*Sample Data 1*

11.01.2022 Belegdatum

I need to get the date (**11.01.2022**) before **Belegdatum**

**Case 2**

*Sample Data 2*

532,53 0,00 0,00 **532,53 EUR** 0034906 38436 DEMMMM

*Sample Data 3*

532,53 0,00 0,00 **4567,00 EUR** 0034906 38436 DEMMMM

I need to get the data **532,53** and **EUR**, means search for currency (**EUR**) and get the amount (**532,53**) or (4567,00) in case of sample data 3. The number can vary from 3 digits to 5 digits before the comma(**,**)

Thank you in advance for the great support.

Answer (score 0):

For both cases, you need to use positive lookahead

case 1:

```
(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})(?=\s?Belegdatum)
```

you can change the regex date to whatever date formate you have

case 2:

considering there are two digits after the comma, the regex to match samples 2 and 3 will be:

```
(\d{3,5},\d{2})(?=\s?EUR)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I also need to extract the currency type EUR

Comment: This will extract them both:

\d{3,5},\d{2}\s?\w{2,3}

and it will match: 

532,53 EUR

considering there is always a comma